# Как отправить голосовое сообщение через VK API на Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Добрый день, мне понадобилось отправлять голосовые сообщения через VK API используя Python (делаю бота для личных нужд, и хотелось бы, что бы он имел возможность отправлять голосовые). Искал в интернете, как это сделать, но находил это только для Java и прочих языков. Помогите пожалуйста с этим вопросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Голосовое сообщение - обычный документ, который мы прикрепляем к сообщению, передавая его идентификатор вида `<type><owner_id>_<media_id>` в качестве параметра `attachment` метода `messages.send` ([описание метода message.send](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send)).

Загрузка аудиосообщения описана в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files_3?f=12.%2B%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%2B%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) следующим образом:

```py
import requests
import json
import vk

import random

session = vk.Session(access_token="ВАШ ACCESS TOKEN")
api = vk.API(session, v="5.131")

# Сначала необходимо получить адрес для загрузки файла.
# Допустимые форматы: Ogg Opus. 
# Ограничения: sample rate 16kHz, variable bitrate 16 kbit/s, 
# длительность не более 5 минут, моно. 

upload_url = api.docs.getMessagesUploadServer(type="audio_message")["upload_url"]

# Затем передать файл на полученный адрес, сформировав POST-запрос 
# с полем file, содержащем наш файл в формате multipart/form-data

r = requests.post(upload_url, files={
    "file": open("ваш_файл.ogg", "rb")
})

# Результат запроса - json объект с полем "file"
# Сохранение документа происходит посредством вызова метода docs.save 
# с передачей ему параметра file, полученного предыдущим запросом

file = r.json()["file"]
document = api.docs.save(file=file)["audio_message"]
```

После того, как наш документ успешно загружен, мы можем отправить его, прикрепив к сообщению:

```
owner_id = document["owner_id"]
id = document["id"]

api.messages.send(
    peer_id = "peer_id получателя",
    random_id = random.randint(0, 2147483647),
    attachment = f"doc{owner_id}_{id}"
)
```